# How would 「問わず語りの心」 translate into English?

Tags: translation, phrases, song-lyrics

It's a line from [寺尾]{てらお}[聰]{あきら}'s ルビーの[指環]{ゆびわ}

> くもり硝子の向うは風の街
>
> **問わず語りの心が切ないね**
>
> 枯葉ひとつの重さもない命
>
> 貴方を失ってから

Youtube Timestamp: https://youtu.be/ICJc53FXu4g?t=16

Now, I understand what he is trying to say overall but I find it hard to put 「問わず語りの心が切ないね」in English. I understood that line as "My painful heart which keeps talking even when nobody asks" but I wonder if there's a better way to put this thing in English. Dictionary shows "unsolicited/unprompted remark" but I think (correct my if I am wrong) it does not translate well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, although I'm not sure how far what your "keeps talking even when nobody asks" implies is from my understanding, sometimes people feel compelled to relate their story to a stranger in front of them, even without clear solicitation by the listener. This is what we usually call 問わず語り.

Next:

> My painful heart which keeps talking even when nobody asks

I can say that it has a clear comprehension error, that is, you try to let 切ない qualify 心. While adjectives can only take one が argument syntactically, whose relation with the word is not immediately clear, 切ない is a mental adjective, and the source of emotion is always assigned to a sentient being. Plus, Japanese prohibits from stating others' emotion in direct forms. Thus, you should take 切ない "painful to me" here.

With above, the phrase could be translated like:

> it's so sad that (my) heart spontaneously pours forth words
>   the helpless thing is (my) heart which ——

What "words" that I used means is unclear from grammar, but I guess from the context that it might refer to this song itself.